# Changing the variable in the column

Tags: r

I got a huge data set which includes one of the column as below:

```
Name
Experiment1
Experiment2_1
Experiment3_1
Experiment2_1
Experiment1
Experiment3_1
Data1
Data2_1
Data3_1
```

This column is made only by those six different names. I would like to change each of them to:

```
Experiment1 -> C_First
Experiment2_1 -> C_Second
Experiment3_1 -> C_Third
Data1 -> T_First
Data2_1 -> T_Second
Data3_1 -> T_Third
```

Is it possible to do in R ? The name of this column is "Name". There are like 20 more different columns in this data set but most of them are filled with the values.

Comment: Take a look at the `?factor` function as well as `?levels`.  They do exactly this.

Comment: Can you show me that on an example ?

Comment: To be a little more precise, note that in this case you should use the second usage of `levels`, that is `levels(x) <- e` (where `e` is an expression), with the possible variant `levels(x)[i] <- e` where `i` are one or more index values.

Comment: I really would be so grateful to show it on an example so I may try it with my data. It's really hard to understand for me what you want me to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since noone else got into more detail, I will (hopefully being right):

```
#random data to simulate yours (but with shorter names...)
DF <- data.frame(Name = c("Exp1", "Exp2_1", "Exp3_1", 
       "Exp2_1", "Exp1", "Exp3_1", "Dat1", "Dat2_1", "Dat3_1"), stringsAsFactors = F)
#> DF
#    Name
#1   Exp1
#2 Exp2_1
#3 Exp3_1
#4 Exp2_1
#5   Exp1
#6 Exp3_1
#7   Dat1
#8 Dat2_1
#9 Dat3_1

#turn the column to factor
DF$Name <- factor(DF$Name)
#> DF$Name
#[1] Exp1   Exp2_1 Exp3_1 Exp2_1 Exp1   Exp3_1 Dat1   Dat2_1 Dat3_1
#Levels: Dat1 Dat2_1 Dat3_1 Exp1 Exp2_1 Exp3_1

#change the levels like the way you want
levels(DF$Name) <- list(C_1 = "Exp1", C_2 = "Exp2_1", 
       C_3 = "Exp3_1", T_1 = "Dat1", T_2 = "Dat2_1", T_3 = "Dat3_1")
```

Values change automatically:

```
#> DF$Name
#[1] C_1 C_2 C_3 C_2 C_1 C_3 T_1 T_2 T_3
#Levels: C_1 C_2 C_3 T_1 T_2 T_3

#> DF
#  Name
#1  C_1
#2  C_2
#3  C_3
#4  C_2
#5  C_1
#6  C_3
#7  T_1
#8  T_2
#9  T_3
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to `factor` the column and change its `levels`

```
d <- data.frame(a=rep(letters[1:3], 10), b=runif(30), stringsAsFactors=TRUE)
str(d)
```

If you're like me, I have `options(stringsAsFactors=FALSE)` in my profile so I am explicitly setting it here.  However, the default behavior in `R` is to make any string column a `factor` when it is read in using a `read.csv` like function.

```
levels(d$a)
# [1] "a" "b" "c"
```

Then we can assign to them:

```
levels(d$a) <- LETTERS[1:3]

levels(d$a)
# [1] "A" "B" "C"
```

Comment: So this is a way to make a data frame with stringsAsFactors and how to already transform a column in data frame to a factor ? Anyway, it's very useful.